# MYSQL Data retrieval through php search

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve some data from mysql.User is supposed to enter the licence number and click search and all records related to that number should be displayed. Unfortunately when i enter licence number and press search then nothing gets displayed. Please see my code below and see where iam going wrong.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("cant connect");
mysql_select_db("android_api")or die("cant connect");
$output='';
//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq=$_POST['search'];

    //if(isset($_POST['search'])){ to if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {   

    //$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fineregister WHERE licencenum LIKE '%$searchq%'")  or die("cant connect");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fineregister WHERE licencenum LIKE  '%".$searchq."%'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count==0){
        $output='no results';
    }else{
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $fdriver=$row['driver'];
            $flicencenum=$row['licencenum'];
            $fofficer=$row['officer'];
            $fspeed=$row['speed'];
            $ffine=$row['fine'];
            $fcategory=$row['category'];
            $output.='<div> '.$fdriver.' '.$flicencenum.' '.$fspeed.' '.$ffine.'  '.$fcategory.'</div>';

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the version with `or die`? Maybe you're getting a MySQL error, but you're not showing it.

Comment: And when you use `or die`, you should use `or die(mysql_error())` so you see the reason.

Comment: Please be sure to sanitize your inputs. You're allowing a `$_POST` variable directly into a query.

Comment: When you say nothing do you mean `no results` is being shown or literally nothing is happening?

Comment: @SamT, what exactly do you mean when you say sanitize inputs. I am new at all this so get my usual stuck ups here and there

Comment: i dont get any results at all. so i just dont know why.

Comment: what would happen if I put something like `a% UNION SELECT user AS driver,password AS licencenum FROM users; #` as my search value, for example

Comment: stop using mysql for God's sake.. it's deprecated.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Is your HTML form POST or GET?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this done. Simply wrote a set of new codes and they worked. i Just need to apply abit of formatting so that the output comes out neatly.

```
      <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());


mysql_select_db("android_api") or die(mysql_error());

?>

 <head>
<title>Search results</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$query = $_GET['query'];
$min_length = 3;


if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE (`licence` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        echo "<p><h3>".$results['driver']." </h3>".$results['licence'].$results['officer'].$results['speed'].$results['fine'].$results['category']."</p>";

        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "No results";
    }

  }
else{ 
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
 ?>
```